# Broken links when MVC project is uploaded to the WebServer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a MVC project and I publish him in my Web Server with IIS

but some button, I have the following code

**Javascript**

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
   window.location.href = "/Home/Login";
});
```

This is just a sample.

When I click in my button, the Login method of my Home Controller is triggered. This works fine in localhost.

When I put the project in the server, I need change the `href` to put the folder name where the application are in `wwwroot`

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
   window.location.href = "/Web/Home/Login";
});
```

How can I prevent this ? 
I have too many images and functions that don't use the folder name in wwwroot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this in your razor view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';
</script>
```

and you can refer `baseUrl` in your js code

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
    window.location.href = baseUrl + "Home/Login";
});
```

The `baseUrl` will give you the result `/Web/` and it should direct your call to the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) helper method. It Generates a fully qualified URL to an action method.

**HTML**

```
<button id='btn' data-url='@Url.Action("Login","Home")'>Login</button>
```

**JS**

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
   window.location.href = $(this).data('url');
});
```